# Normal/Bump map show in Look Dev but not on Render

Tags: rendering, shaders, texture-baking, baking

I am trying to bake a diffuse texture with all the shaders applied to it, including the bump map effect just applied to the texture instead of having a seperate normal map.
In Look Dev I can see the result I want to achieve, but when I switch the viewport to Render the bump map is missing.
I watched several tutorials already but I am apparently still missing something crucial and just can't figure out what.

This picture shows my shader setup and settings for the bake. Also you can see what I am trying to achieve in the Look Dev Viewport compared to the Render I get.
[image: Shader setup and viewports]

[image]

Comment: The shader to RGB node is not supported in Cycles.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I did some more testing around and finally came to a solution. Apparently a *Mix Shader* into a *Shader to RGB* make the bump map get renderer in *Look Dev* but not in *Render*. The solution (and in hindsight the more reasonable) approach is to use a *Mix RGB* node instead.
I'm not sure if this can be considerer as just plain stupidity or of it's an actual bug.

Here is my new setup that works:
[image]